# error in configuring sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i made an user in sqlserver2008 which its name is test1 and my computers name is  WIN-NKQENDDOCT0 and run management shell but happend follow error :

```
The local farm is not accessible. Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered.

PS C:\Users\Administrator> New-SPConfigurationDatabase
cmdlet New-SPConfigurationDatabase at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
DatabaseName: Sharepoint_config
DatabaseServer: WIN-NKQENDDOCT0
FarmCredentials
Passphrase: ********
New-SPConfigurationDatabase : \test1
At line:1 char:28
+ New-SPConfigurationDatabase <<<<
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...urationDatabase:
  SPCmdletNewSPConfigurationDatabase) [New-SPConfigurationDatabase], SPExcep
 tion
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSPCon
  figurationDatabase
```

please help me 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Run your SharePoint Management Shell with Farm Administrator and grant the Test1 account with rights to SharePoint configuration database using the following command:

```
Add-SPShellAdmin -username Test1
```